# How to stop all web pages of my site being redirected to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I installed Drupal 7 and developed a basic site for a friend  (http://www.misterklean.org.uk)

It was working lovely, then I noticed months later that every single link on the site (including admin links like admin login!) are being redirected to the homepage.

I contacted my hosts who are refusing to help, saying that it's a scripting problem.  The htaccess file hasn't changed since I initially uploaded it - and I've tried re-uploading a default htaccess file which I know works on another of my drupal sites (same hosting company)

I've looked at the server error log file and can't see anything since I'd finished developing the site.
I can post the htaccess file here if people think it might help.

Answer (score 1):

you have not enable the clean URL on the server. so you need to disable the Clean URL form Drupal Admin or database. 
 you can view the pages like below:

```
http://www.misterklean.org.uk/?q=clients
http://www.misterklean.org.uk/?q=payment-options
http://www.misterklean.org.uk/?q=enquiries
```

Comment: "Enable clean URLs" is checked in the admin screen (http://www.misterklean.org.uk/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls)

Comment: "Enable clean URLs" is checked in the admin screen (http://www.misterklean.org.uk/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls)

I unchecked, saved, flushed all caches, (the problem remains)

Then I re-enabled, saved and flushed all caches, but I'm still getting the same problem...

Comment: you need to enable the clean URL on you server. I think you have forced the clean URL in you server configuration. Please review the follow URL:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls